# Offline Demo Save Data to Full Version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I currently do not have the full version of Minecraft, but I've been using the semi-glitch where you can get the full (though not multiplayer, and not updated) version of the game by turning off your WiFi and logging into the demo. I assume this is a pretty well-known way to get around the demo, seeing as I was able to find it on my own. As far as I can tell, the servers do not notice that I do not have the paid version of the game, and therefore still let me into offline mode.

Anyways, I would like to buy the full version sometime, but I was wondering if I would be able to transfer my saves from where they are now. I'm not even sure that I'm even using the demo version right now, which might mean that I'll lose all my save data. I've built up a pretty significant base, and that would really not be fun to redo. Does anyone have information on this?

Comment: Here at Arqade, we don't encourage cheating or hacking, or even exploiting a glitch.

Answer (score 4):

The "demo" is identical to the full version, except that it runs inside your browser window. It uses the same save location as when Minecraft is run from your harddrive, so all your worlds will be right there in your world list if you install the local version, so long as it's the same computer as you've been playing the demo on.

As a note, your demo-workaround isn't necessary – you can download and install the local version of Minecraft without buying a premium account, so you can test this out for yourself. There's a link right there to download Minecraft, and it works without being logged in:

[image]

You'll be able to play in "offline" mode, which means no multiplayer and no customisable skin. You'll also have the benefit of trying out the game using more of your screen, and without the browser chewing up memory, giving you a better idea of what you're getting when you buy. There's also the advantage of not having to turn off your wifi on while playing.